# keybd_event() calls not sending to remote desktop

Tags: c++, winapi, remote-desktop

I am trying to use keybd_event() to press certain keys through to a remote desktop application. For the simplest test I am simply opening notepad in the remote session, and have the call keybd_event() run on the local computer with the current user focus on notepad.

Unfortunately it does not appear to be sending any input through to remote desktop.

If I run the application on the local computer with a local instance of notepad in focus, it types exactly what I want to type no problem.

Does anyone have any ideas why this won't work? Obviously I can type manually into the remote desktop session.

Thanks

Comment: Right click and try running your program as administrator? I had a problem sending key events and mouse events to task manager and running as admin worked.

Comment: Thanks for the response Brandon, unfortunately we've tried that to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried other remote desktop programs? (for example, TeamViewer) It is usual to have problems with standard RDP, but other programs often haven't such strange limitations.

Comment: Thanks @Ilya, unfortunately that's not possible as we are remoting into a supplied PaaS server. So in essence, we HAVE to use RDP...

Comment: I hope you will find simple software solution. But I suspect, that the only way is to use keyboard emulator system (based on Raspberry Pi, Arduino or something like this). One time I've made hardware mouse emulator for similar task... It is not too hard. Good luck in looking for simplier solution!

Comment: Hmm it's weird that it doesn't register the input.. I can't test it as I don't have another computer handy atm.. However, you could try using SetWindowsHookEx and remove the `LLKHF_INJECTED` flag: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967(v=vs.85).aspx  Maybe then it would register as a hardware event and go through. Though, I'm not sure if that actually is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Any Remote Desktop program is a gateway to connect a remote system, it is a mediator. Sending any keyboard message to this program via any method (like `keybd_event`, `SendInput`, `PostMessage` etc.) will be silently absorbed by the RDP program. It simply wont consume it, and wont pass it to the connected resource.

Most probably (which I am not sure of), the program might have documented APIs to send some messages to it, like close-session, open-session, or to send-message-to-connected session. Using given API (function, COM interfaces whatsoever), you *may* send some input to connected resource.

Comment: Since a Remote Desktop window is still a local window like any other window, I would expect input messages sent to such a window to be interpreted as normal user input like any other window would and get transmitted to the remote machine accordingly. Unless the RDP is using `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `RegisterRawInputDevices()` to differentiate between simulated input and physical input, which is a possibility.

Comment: Assume you pressed Ctrl+T combination. Would this be passed to remote? What if that's a shortcut to RDP application itself? That simply says RDP app would process the message in its own way, and only on its decision it will be transmitted to remote. Assume you write such application - do you think everything user types would directly goto remote? If so how?